# Editable and autocomplete combo box with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, combobox, autocomplete

I need to make a combo box in my form to be editable and capable to search the input text through the values of the combo box (like autocomplete way).

What's the simplest way to obtain this?

Answer (score 2):

If you aren't already using any framework that provides this component (i.e. YUI), this component might be useful to you: [dhtmlxCombo](http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxCombo/index.shtml)

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at [Dojo's ComboBox](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dijit/form/ComboBox.html).
It has all the features you require and more.

Answer (score 1):

I am searching for it myself. One of the solutions I've found is [jQuery UI's autocomplete](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete). Seems to be very flexible and well documented. See http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox for example.